# Aggregate function not adding new column MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

When I execute below column it is giving results as column is added , but when I query the table, new column is not showing up.

```
db.getCollection("arcm_qc").aggregate([
 {
        $addFields: {
            MGE_ID: { $arrayElemAt: [{ "$split": ["$MCA Go", "-"] }, 0] }

        }
    }

])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add fields in the collection using only aggregate. But you can use [aggregate in an update query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) like this:

```
db.collection.update({/*the documents you want to update or empty to update all*/},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      MGE_ID: {
        $arrayElemAt: [{"$split": ["$MCA Go","-"]},0]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xq9FGXwUy3w)

Comment: can we add trim to this added field, if so how?

Comment: Do you mean [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1OeX1ASDXJS)

Comment: yes thankyou this is what I was expecting